# How to receive a plain web response in the format of a photo and show it in a picture box?

Tags: c#, vb.net

There is a website which sends back photos of users in plain text. The link to the pages is as follows:

```
http://example.com/getphoto.asp?id=0123456789
```

How can I implement a Windows Forms application in C# or VB.NET that receives the plain data and shows the image in a `PictureBox`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "http://example.com/getphoto.asp?id=0123456789";
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(wc.OpenRead(url));
}
```